# catkin_create_android_repo error: can't encode character

Tags: android-core, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, I am starting with Ros installing Hydro on Ubuntu 13.04 following

> (ROS WIKI URL)/wiki/sig/Rosjava/Android%20Development%20Environment

I can compile android_core ok.

When  I try to create my own repo following

> (ROS WIKI URL)/wiki/rosjava_tools/hydro

I found the follow error:

> $ catkin_create_android_repo my_project android_core rosjava_core android_extras

> [error] 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xed' in position 34: ordinal not in range(128) : <type 'exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError'>

a directory named my_project is created with an empty settings.gradle.

Locales on my machine are set to es_ES.UTF-8, but I have tried putting LC_ALL=C with the same results.

Apt is configured to download ROS packages from "deb PACKAGES_ROS_ORG_URL/ros/ubuntu raring main"

Any help will be wellcome

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69961/catkin_create_android_repo-error:-can%27t-encode-character/) by [Amancio Díaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/5659/amancio-d%C3%ADaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2013-07-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the problem in the user's name (not the login). The script reads /etc/passwords to obtain the user name. In my case it was "Díaz" so when trying to write the "í" in the build.gradle it brakes. Just remove the acute from the user's surname and everything works again.

---

Originally posted by [Amancio Díaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/5659/amancio-d%C3%ADaz/) with karma: 26 on 2013-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1